# SqPaymentForm is not initializing in IOS Device browser

Tags: square, square-connect

SqPaymentForm is not initializing in IOS Device browser

Following is the code I am using to initialize.

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
            paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
              applicationId: Meteor.settings.public.SQUARE_APPLICATION_ID,
              locationId: Meteor.settings.public.SQUARE_LOCATION_ID,
              inputClass: 'form-control',
              inputStyles: [
                  {
                    fontSize: '14px'
                  }
                ],
              cardNumber: {
                elementId: 'sq-card-number',
                placeholder: '0000 0000 0000 0000'
              },
              cvv: {
                elementId: 'sq-cvv',
                placeholder: 'CVV'
              },
              expirationDate: {
                elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
                placeholder: 'MM/YY'
              },
              postalCode: {
                elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
                placeholder: '94110'
              },


              callbacks: {
                methodsSupported: function (methods) {

                  var applePayBtn = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay');
                  var applePayLabel = document.getElementById('sq-apple-pay-label');
                  var masterpassBtn = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass');
                  var masterpassLabel = document.getElementById('sq-masterpass-label');



                  // Only show the button if Apple Pay for Web is enabled
                  // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
                  if (methods.applePay === true) {
                    applePayBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    applePayLabel.style.display = 'none' ;
                  }
                  // Only show the button if Masterpass is enabled
                  // Otherwise, display the wallet not enabled message.
                  if (methods.masterpass === true) {
                    masterpassBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
                    masterpassLabel.style.display = 'none';
                  }
                },
                cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
                  if (errors){

                    $(".cardNumber").html('');
                    $(".cvv").html('');
                    $(".expirationDate").html('');
                    $(".postalCode").html('');

                    for (var i =0; i < errors.length; i++){

                      $("."+errors[i].field).html(errors[i].message);
                    }
                    $("#payment-loader").css('display','none');
                    $("#sq-creditcard").attr('disabled',false);
                    $("#pay-on-delivery").attr('disabled',false);

                }else{
                    $(".cardNumber").html('');
                    $(".cvv").html('');
                    $(".expirationDate").html('');
                    $(".postalCode").html('');

                    var requestDiscount = $("#requestDiscount").val();
                    var totalAmounts = $("#totalAmount").val();
                    var carWashDetails = {
                      recordId: this._id,
                      userId: Meteor.userId(),
                      discount:$("#requestDiscount").val(),
                      discountCoupon: $("#requestDiscountCoupon").val(),
                      discountType: $("#requestDiscountType").val()
                    };
                    Meteor.call("makeSquarePayment", cardData, nonce, totalAmounts, requestDiscount, carWashRequestId, carWashDetails, function(res){

                    });
                }


                },
                unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
                  // Alert the buyer
                  alert('ddd');
                },
                createPaymentRequest: function () {
                  return {
                    requestShippingAddress: false,
                    currencyCode: "USD",
                    countryCode: "US",

                    total: {
                      label: "#{square_location_name}",
                      amount: "1.01",
                      pending: false,
                    },

                    lineItems: [
                      {
                        label: "Subtotal",
                        amount: "1.00",
                        pending: false,
                      },
                      {
                        label: "Tax",
                        amount: "0.01",
                        pending: false,
                      }
                    ]
                  };
                },
                paymentFormLoaded: function() {
                    console.log("form loaded Successful");
                }
              }
            });

        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function(){console.log("fff");paymentForm.build();},6000);
```

Below is the HTML portion:

```
<div class="app-card pay-summary mrg-bottom-small">
          <h2 class="heading-title">Card Details</h2>
          <div class="common-table" >
          <form id="nonce-form" name="payment-form">
              <div class='card-wrapper'></div>
                  <div class="card-details">

                    <div class="alert alert-danger error-payment display-hide"></div>

                    <div class="form-group car-section">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="select-box">
                            <label>Card Number</label>
                            <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
                            <span class="errorSpan cardNumber"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group car-section">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="select-box">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control makeRequired" id="card-name" name="card-name" placeholder="Name On Card">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group car-section">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="select-box">
                            <label>CVV</label>
                            <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
                            <span class="errorSpan cvv"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group car-section">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="select-box">
                            <label>Expiry Date</label>
                            <div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
                            <span class="errorSpan expirationDate"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group car-section">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                          <div class="select-box">
                            <label>Postal Code</label>
                            <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
                            <span class="errorSpan postalCode"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="totalAmount" name="totalAmount" value="{{getPlanDetailsOriginal.total}}">
                  </div>

               <table class="table">
                <tbody> 

                  {{#if checkPaymentStatus.payment}}
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button title="Pay" class="btn btn-block" id="sq-creditcard" type="button" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)" >Pay</button></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button title="Pay On Delivery" class="btn btn-block" id="pay-on-delivery" type="submit">Pay On Delivery</button></td>
                  </tr>

                  {{/if}}

                  <div align="center" id="payment-loader" class="display-hide">
                      <img src="/images/loading.gif" height="50" width="50">
                  </div>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The above code is working properly in Android, PC Browsers. Only not working in Device Browsers.

I have added `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>` at the header of the page.

Also added Css of the square connect from the website.

Also used whole tutorial in other project to check but get the same error in all.

Comment: What browser are you using on iOS? Are you receiving any errors? Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: I am using Safari in IOS and no error is coming. I have tried in both local and https server. It gives me same.

Comment: Just to be clear - you said it works on Android devices? So if you use Chrome on your iOS, does it load correctly? I just want to narrow down the issue.

Comment: No it is not loading in any of the browsers of device.

Comment: OK so it works on your PC, but not mobile devices. What exactly happens? Does the iframes just not load?

Comment: iframes loads but form does not initialize properly. No placeholders loads in the text boxes and just the form does not load fully.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem was discussed in the squareup forum.

https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/Developer-Discussions/Square-form-gives-warning-sometimes-does-not-load/td-p/131371

> It sounds like they’re trying to initialize the square payment form
>   before actually showing it. They should either:
>
> 1) Initialize it only at the last step (rather than before they’re on that step)
>
> or
>
> 2) Initialize it with autoBuild: false and then call build() when they
>   need to show it (see more info about that here https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/how-it-works#single-page-web-applications-customizi...)